# Does the Typescript compiler expose the default value of JsDoc @param?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I expected to be able to extract the default value of a JsDoc param but I'm actually unable to find the default value on the JsDoc node. For example, give this:

/**
 * @param [foo=42] This is foo!
 */

I'd like to extract '42' from the node. Yet I find no default value field on the ts node:

[image]

It exposes `isBracketed` but I cannot find the `42`. Typescript does claim to support default JsDoc arguments:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript#param-and-returns

Yet I cannot seem to find the exposed in the AST... :<

Before I log a bug, I figured I'd ask around and see if anyone knows the secret handshake.

Comment: Issue opened here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not currently in the AST. The parser currently skips over the expression without storing the return value anywhere.

```
// May have an optional default, e.g. '[foo = 42]'
if (parseOptionalToken(SyntaxKind.EqualsToken)) {
    parseExpression();
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3a2f6a3ed1a598a241e7c750873105f22e7a2463/src/compiler/parser.ts#L6711)